# Why is my async function hanging when calling task.run function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, task

I want to make a function async since I'd like to return the results to the UI and don't want to make this hang, but it is anyway.

Can someone tell me why this would be hanging?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(FunctionThreeAsync().Result);
}

private async Task<MyType> FunctionThreeAsync()
{
    return await FunctionThree();
}

private Task<MyType> FunctionThree()
{
    return Task.Run<MyType>(() => { /* code */ });
}
```

Comment: return View(await FunctionThreeAsync());

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This:

```
return View(FunctionThreeAsync().Result);
```

Is deadlocking your code. [You shouldn't be blocking on an async method](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). Instead, mark your method as `async`, make it return a `Task<T>` and `await` the call:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DoStuffAsync()
{
    return View(await FunctionThreeAsync());
}
```

Async goes all the way. When you have a method that's async, it will need to be asynchronously waited on, not synchronously blocked on. This means spreading `async` throughout your code base.

Comment: There is an article in the July MSDN magazine with some notes regarding brownfield async that I found interesting regarding blocking etc. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404

Comment: Here's another good article to throw in the fire: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html Also, check out the resources at the bottom of that article.

Comment: @KoBE That's the article I referenced in my answer :)